# eBay MIP: Delete inventory item

Tags: csv, sftp

I need to access the eBay Merchant Integration Platform **via SFTP**. Using the web CSV upload is not an option, because I want to automate the process.

It works as I can upload products, update quantities, prices, and receive offers periodically. However, I fail to delete an inventory item (which is not the same as setting the quantity to 0, which works fine).

I tried to upload my `delete-inventory.csv` to the `store/inventory` folder on the SFTP server, but the error message in the response CSV looks as if eBay interprets the file as a 'normal' `inventory.csv`.

**My question is:** To which of the folders (e.g. `store/availability`, `store/distribution`, `store/product`) should I upload my `delete-inventory.csv` if not to the `store/inventory` folder?

Call me dumb but I'm unable to find it in the docs.

Here's my `delete-inventory.csv`:

```
SKU,Action,Channel ID,Format
test-sku,DeleteInventory,EBAY_US,FIXED_PRICE
```

And here's the eBay response CSV:

```
SKU, Group ID, Locale, ePID, Channel ID, Item ID, Status, Message Type, Message ID, Message
test-sku,,,,,,FAILED,ERROR,335101,Invalid request for SKU. Atleast one of shipToLocationAvailability or offers is required.
```

NB: The same happened when I removed the optional columns `Channel ID` and `Format` from my `delete-inventory.csv` or when I played around with optional/mandatory columns. It does not seem to be a syntactical problem.

Thanks for your help!

Reference: https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/merchant-products/mipng/regular/content/user-guide/definitions-delete-inventory-feed.html?tocpath=Managing%20inventory%7CFeed%20definitions%7C_____10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the eBay support and they told me to use the `store/deleteInventory` folder. This folder had neither appeared in the directory tree of two SFTP clients on two computers nor in the web interface, but after I contacted them, it was suddenly there...

Answer (score 0):

While EBAY MIP is marketed as "easy to use", it is far from being so. If even the sample files contain errors much less a file from scratch.
Uploads are producing error codes that does not even have proper explanations. More over, an upload will produce an error, you have it corrected, then different error message occurs on future uploads.
Today is my second day uploading a test file and I am still not successful.